# Split VPN in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, dnsmasq

So I need to work on a Ruby web application that consumes both public and private services, so part of the services' urls point to the internet, and part of it points to services only available on the intranet. It seems that by editing `/etc/resolv.conf` I can make work only one set of them. Whatever is the first line will be working. So I try to setup dnsmasq to split VPN but still no success. Here is my current setup:

```
/etc/resolv.conf:

    nameserver 127.0.0.1


/etc/dnsmasq.conf:

    server=/mycompany.com/<ip-of-dns-server>
    server=<ip-my-ISPs-dns>
    interface=lo
    listen-address=127.0.0.1
    no-resolv
```

The config file seemd to be picked up because if I write something like

```
server=/google.hu/<ip-my-ISPs-dns>
```

Then I can `ping google.hu` e.g. and not other public sites.

The symptom is that I cannot e.g. ping addresses on the intranet:

```
ping: <some-company-url>.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I appreciate any help setting this up.